# Integrate for f(t,x) dt

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

I have to calculate $$(\displaystyle \int_{0}^x f(t,x) dt )'$$

I actually don't have much idea, i thought that it was like f(t,x) or something like that, but after some examples I haven't found an idea. 
Thanks if you can help me.

Comment: You have $t$ as your integration upper bound, and then dt in your integration.. that is not quite right.. Did you mean $x$ for the upper-bound? And then the derivative is in terms of $x$, right?

Comment: Yes, i'll correct it, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem solves using [Leibniz_integral_rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule). For your case,

$$\frac d {dx} \int_0^x f(t,x)\,dt=f(x,x)+\int_0^x \left(\frac d {dx}f(t,x)\right)\,dt$$